# How to import and program in UDK

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I am currently learning UDK tutorials but I dont understand how to make real game with this like exporting my maya models and its animation rigs etc etc like in unity we do. Also how do I program my characters, AI for enemies etc. Please convey your opinion how to go advance with UDK ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a very big topic.  There is a lot of learning material on the web for UDK but it's less user-friendly than Unity. Importing maya models here: http://cg.tutsplus.com/tutorials/autodesk-maya/maya-to-udk-importing-static-meshes-using-actorx-fbx/  For larger programming questions you'll probably need a book length guide like [http://www.amazon.com/Unreal-Development-Game-Programming-UnrealScript/dp/1849691924](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849691924)

Answer (score 1):

Creating an entire game is a hard and time consuming project.

First of all I would recommend that you start with a small project, even though it is tempting to just go ahead and make the game of your dreams. Been down that road before..

Go to this page: http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/WebHome.html and click and read everything that is relevant to your game.

This is important so that you have a small understanding of everything before you start.

Then go ahead and follow some tutorials, and you'll probably have to read most of the documentation again..

I know this seems hard, but to get it right, this is the way to go..